# Why does JObject.Parse() not invoke PropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, json

I am using JSON.NET in C#. In my Code, a Json String gets periodically parsed to the `JObject dataObj`. Everytime the `dataObj` gets changed, I want the new one be displayed in a textbox in the UI. This is why I thought of this code:

```
    internal void DisplayData()
    {
        dataObj.PropertyChanged += DataObj_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private async void DataObj_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        await dataBox.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, 
                              delegate { dataBox.Text = writeString; });
    }
```

`writestring` is the to a `string` converted `dataObj`.

I expected the `DataObj_PropertyChanged()` to be executed everytime, the line `dataObj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);` is reached, but it is not.

How could I solve this? Is there an alternative?

Thank you.

Comment: You're asking us why your `dataObj` field or property doesn't raise `PropertyChanged` when you assign a value to it, is that right? Well, you've seen the code and we haven't. You tell us. But I can tell you one thing: If you REPLACE the value of `dataObj`, that won't make the old value raise any events.

Comment: @SirRufo Read my whole comment.

Comment: @EdPlunkett After three times reading I got it :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *owner* of `dataObj` needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` if you want to be able to raise `PropertyChanged` when you assign a new value to `dataObj`.

I'm assuming that `dataObj` is a field or property of some class. It needs to be a property of that class.

But maybe you don't need to raise `PropertyChanged`. If all you want to do is have your own class call a method when it changes the value of `DataObj`, just do that in the property setter.

```
private JObject _dataObj;
public JObject DataObj {
    get { return _dataObj; }
    set {
        if (_dataObj != value) {
            _dataObj = value;

            OnDataObjChanged();

            //  Maybe you don't really need this, I can't say. 
            //OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DataObj));
        }
    }
}

protected async void OnDataObjChanged()
{
    await 
        dataBox.Dispatcher.RunAsync(
            Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, 
            delegate { _dataBox.Text = writeString; }
        );
}
```

If you just replace the value of `dataObj`, the old value of `dataObj` isn't going to raise any events. Why would it? How could it?

Comment: Your Interpretation was correct and I just didn't see the most obvious solution. Thanks :D

Comment: @Nayangar Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `DataObj_PropertyChanged` is never raised is because you have not attached that method to **that instance** which got changed.

Your code looks something like

```
JObject dataObj;

// Create a new JObject instance from a jsonString
dataObj = JObject.Parse( jsonString );
dataObj.PropertyChanged += DataObj_PropertyChanged;

// Create a new JObject instance from a jsonString
dataObj = JObject.Parse( jsonString );
```

`DataObj_PropertyChanged` will be called if you change a property on the **instance** where you have attached it. But you create a new instance without an attached `DataObj_PropertyChanged`.